# Public Knowledge Base for Lightning Knowledge

Tags: lightning-knowledge

We are looking for various solutions to expose lightning knowledge articles to external users (Like... PKB). There is an appexchange application available for Salesforce classic knowledge, but not for Lightning Knowledge. Is building my own custom solution only option available or any other options that I can explore?

Thanks,
Ashok.

Comment: You want knowledge articles in communites?

Comment: Hi @PranayJaiswal - Not in communities.

Comment: then where do you want to display your knowledge articles?

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of the Help Center Community template. There is no additional charge for this community as the cost of communities comes from logins. So, if it is public only there is no charge.

"The Help Center template offers a public-facing, self-service portal where guest users can search your knowledge base for answers to their questions."

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_help_center_template.htm&type=0